# Paypal button for membership and donate amount

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to have a membership button and then at checkout also have a way for a member to add a donation amount? I am using Joomla and not sure if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible, generate your donate button at paypal site: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

Comment: Not sure I understand. I have a button for membership but when the check out at the PayPal site I would like them to be able to also add in a donation amount there.